# AngularJS ng-model gives blank option in select tag

Tags: html, angularjs

Whenever I use ng-model, it gives a blank option for my `select` tag.

So here's my HTML:

```
    <label> Select Email Template</label>
    <select ng-change="vm.previewMessage(this)" ng-model="vm.emailSelectedMessage" class="form-control">
        <option ng-repeat="message in vm.messages" ng-if="message.type === 1" ng-disabled="vm.isProcessing" ng-value="message.id">
            {{ message.name }}
        </option>
    </select>

    <label> Select SMS Template</label>
    <select ng-change="vm.previewMessage(this)" ng-model="vm.smsSelectedMessage" class="form-control">
        <option ng-repeat="message in vm.messages" ng-if="message.type === 2" ng-disabled="vm.isProcessing" ng-value="message.id">
            {{ message.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
```

And here's my JS:

```
vm.emailSelectedMessage = 0;
vm.smsSelectedMessage = 0;

function loadMessages() {
          Messages
              .query()
              .$promise
              .then(function(result) {
                  vm.messages = result;
              }, function(error) {
                  console.error(error);
              });
      }
```

Comment: make sure you are having same values in `vm.emailSelectedMessage` and the ng-value of any option

Comment: @Aakriti.G I can't manually do that, the options came from a query.

Comment: Do one thing check with inspect element and check if values are same or not

Comment: It worked, I changed `vm.emailSelectedMessage` to `1` and it didn't show any blank options. But that data can be deleted, and if it happens it will turn to a blank option again.

Comment: Change your select as `<select ng-change="vm.previewMessage(this)" ng-model="vm.emailSelectedMessage" ng-init="vm.emailSelectedMessage = vm.messages[0].id" class="form-control">`, it should work.

Comment: You should use ngOptions instead of ngRepeat.

Comment: @AnkitVadi doesn't work.

Comment: @nicolascolman I tried using ngOptions instead of ngRepeat too. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong when I try ngOptions.

Comment: My intention is you must have to initialize `ng-model` of select tags with any of options available to them and that will put away empty options.

Comment: But how can I do that dynamically @AnkitVadi

Answer (score 0):

```
vm.selectMessage = function(msgType) {
  var msgId = null;
  vm.messages.forEach(msg, function(value) {
    if(msg.type == msgType) {
      msgId = msg.id;
      return;
    }
  });
  return msgId;
}
```

Before loadMessages(), write one function in your controller mentioned above. Then change your select tags as mentioned below.

```
<label> Select Email Template</label>
<select ng-change="vm.previewMessage(this)" ng-model="vm.emailSelectedMessage" ng-init="vm.emailSelectedMessage = vm.selectMessage(1)" class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="message in vm.messages" ng-if="message.type === 1" ng-disabled="vm.isProcessing" ng-value="message.id">
        {{ message.name }}
    </option>
</select>

<label> Select SMS Template</label>
<select ng-change="vm.previewMessage(this)" ng-model="vm.smsSelectedMessage" ng-init="vm.smsSelectedMessage = vm.selectMessage(2)" class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="message in vm.messages" ng-if="message.type === 2" ng-disabled="vm.isProcessing" ng-value="message.id">
        {{ message.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Try above code. Might help!!

Comment: I don't understand the write a function part. I'll add it on my loadMessages() function?

Comment: loadMessage is function of your angular controller. Right? This should have written like `$scope.loadMessages = function() { ... }`. Is it so?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't write it like that. My example on my post is what's exactly what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it in a dynamic way by modifying my loadMessages() function.

```
function loadMessages() {
        Messages
            .query()
            .$promise
            .then(function(result) {
                _.each(result, function (r, i) {
                  if (vm.emailSelectedMessage === 0) {
                    if (result[i].type === 1) {
                      vm.emailSelectedMessage = result[i].id;
                    }
                  }

                  if (vm.smsSelectedMessage === 0) {
                      if (result[i].type === 2) {
                          vm.smsSelectedMessage = result[i].id;
                      }
                  }
                });
                vm.messages = result;
            }, function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

We can not use two way binding in  tag, instead of this please use this. It print drop down values.

```
<label> Select Email Template</label>
    <select ng-change="vm.previewMessage(this)" ng-model="vm.emailSelectedMessage" class="form-control">
      <option ng-repeat="message in vm.messages" ng-if="message.type === 1" ng-disabled="vm.isProcessing" value="{{ message.name }}">
      </option>
    </select>

    <label> Select SMS Template</label>
    <select ng-change="vm.previewMessage(this)" ng-model="vm.smsSelectedMessage" class="form-control">
      <option ng-repeat="message in vm.messages" ng-if="message.type === 2" ng-disabled="vm.isProcessing" value="{{ message.name }}">
      </option>
    </select>
```